# DAX Calculated column to consider multiple rows to generate a result

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset like this.

```
Reference_ID        MyCode        
1                   NULL                
1                   S1010             
1                   NULL
1                   1011
2                   NULL  
2                   NULL
```

I want to return True for 1, as 1 has a value other than empty or blank or NULL. While False for 2.

```
Reference_ID        MyCode        ExpectedOutput
1                   NULL              True
1                   S1010             True
1                   NULL              True
1                   1011              True
2                   NULL              False
2                   NULL              False
```

How can I do this using DAX in Power BI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

I made use of the COUNTROWS function to do this.

```
Non_NULL_MyCodes = 
        Var required_PolicyNumber = (Sheet1[Reference_ID])
        Var numberofRows = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),Sheet1[Reference_ID] = required_PolicyNumber && Sheet1[MyCode] <> "NULL")))
        Var result = IF(numberofRows>0,True,False)
return result
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like,

```
ExpectedOutPut =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    Reference_ID = 1, TRUE (),
    Reference_ID = 2, FALSE (),
    BLANK ()
)
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking.You need to group by Id first, then find if a group has at least one non blank value, and only then decide true or false. Your code can't do that.

Comment: My bad, If that's the OP's ask then definetly this code would not work. Better to filter table first then apply the logic.